# How do I set a current_user in Rack middleware for GraphQL

Tags: ruby, graphql, devise, rack, warden

I'm using GraphQLPlayground configured in my `config.ru`

```
  map "/graphql-playground" do
    use GraphqlPlaygroundAuthentication
    use GraphQLPlayground, endpoint: "/graphql"
  end
end
```

And I want to authorize my requests via `GraphqlPlaygroundAuthentication` since Rack does not send cookies with the request.

In my `graphql_controller.rb` I have this:

```
def execute
    variables = prepare_variables(params[:variables])
    query = params[:query]
    operation_name = params[:operationName]
    context = {
      current_actor: current_user
    }
    # more code here
```

How do I set `current_user` inside of `GraphqlPlaygroundAuthentication.rb`?
I have tried to set cookies with `Rack::Utils.set_cookie_header!` but even though I see the cookies inside Application tab in my browser, my `current_user` inside request is `nil`.

I have no idea how to set the `current_user` to be available inside the controller and then my playground requests are unauthorized.

Reason why Playground is mounted inside `config.ru` and not `routes.rb`: CSP configuration of my project. I cannot change that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `current_user` method in your `controllers/application_controller.rb`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  def current_user
    # If test situation when user is logged in
    User.first

    # If test situation when user is not logged in
    # nil
  end
end
```